# Google maps not working for Ruby on Rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am following the tutorial to bring up maps on web page but its not working.
Following error throws up:

undefined local variable or method `acts_as_gmappable' for #<Class:0x4b7e750>
app/models/character.rb:2:in`'
app/models/character.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/characters_controller.rb:7:in`index'

I have tried almost everything I could: restarted the server, bundle install and bundle update:

Here are the relevant files.

characters_controller.rb

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_character, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /characters
  # GET /characters.json
  def index
    @characters = Character.all
    json = Character.all.to_gmaps4rails
  end

  # GET /characters/1
  # GET /characters/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /characters/new
  def new
    @character = Character.new
  end
```

character.rb

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_gmappable

    def gmaps4rails_address
        address
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing characters</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Longitude</th>
      <th>Latitude</th>
      <th>Gmaps</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @characters.each do |character| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= character.name %></td>
        <td><%= character.address %></td>
        <td><%= character.longitude %></td>
        <td><%= character.latitude %></td>
        <td><%= character.gmaps %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', character %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_character_path(character) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', character, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Character', new_character_path %>
<%= gmaps4rails(#json) %>
```

If you need any more information from me please let me know. I have already spent a lot of time on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what tutorial are you following?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg5-33zedqM .... The Apneadiving

Comment: @sevenseacat http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg5-33zedqM  ... The Apneadiving

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is deprecated, only works for 1.x version.

Documentation in wiki states to follow this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0l-7en3dUw&feature=youtu.be